# Get python to look for words and output them

Tags: python

I've been looking into developing a discord bot that can reply to messages by reading their contents and checking if they appear in a list.

My problem is, I need to find a reliable way of getting python to look for certain words from a text, see if they appear in the given list and output the words that are detected.

I've managed to get it working somewhat myself with the following code:

```
if any(word in text in list):
     print("Word Spotted")
```

I would really apreciate some help.

Comment: Hard to say. The problem (as I see it) is how to scan every line of text the moment its typed out but before its allowed into the discord chat. The actual scanning of strings is the easy part.

Comment: That two lines of code don't do what you are asking?

Comment: @usr2564301 Those two lines sometimes cause several messages to be sent instead of just one, I didn't think it through entirely.

Comment: @Rob The bot only looks into the messages once they have been sent, I used the following code to obtain the messages as strings:                                                                                                         "@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content"   I cannot get this to be displayed as code

Comment: @SiegmundEurades See Jesse's reply, that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that does something like what you're describing. But really it sounds like you need to spend a significant amount of time working through some basic Python tutorials before you will be able to implement this.

```
import re

key_words = set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

typed_str = 'You are such a Foo BAR!'

print key_words & set(re.findall('[a-z]+', typed_str.lower()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what is being asked but somethings to consider (in no particular order) if you are building a bot that is taking in raw user input.

1. capitalization sensitivity
2. spell check
3. understanding intent simplistically

If your environment allows access to libraries you might consider checking out [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/). The following commands will give you the functionality needed for the example below.

`pip install textblob`

`python -m textblob.download_corpora`

## core function

```
from textblob import TextBlob, Word
import copy

def score_intent(rawstring,keywords,weights=None,threshold=0.01,debug=False):
    """
    rawstring: string of text with words that you want to detect
    keywords: list of words that you are looking for
    weights: (optional) dictionary with relative weights of words you want
    threshold: spellcheck confidence threshold
    debug: boolean for extra print statements to help debug
    """
    allwords = TextBlob(rawstring).words
    allwords = [w.upper() for w in allwords]
    keywords = [k.upper() for k in keywords]
    processed_input_as_list = spellcheck_subject_matter_specific(rawstring,keywords,threshold=threshold,debug=debug)
    common_words = intersection(processed_input_as_list,keywords)
    intent_score = len(common_words)
    if weights:
        for special_word in weights.keys():
            if special_word.upper() in common_words:
                # the minus one is so we dont double count a word.
                intent_score = intent_score + weights[special_word] -1 

    if debug:
        print "intent score: %s" %intent_score
        print "words of interest found in text: {}".format(common_words)
    # you could return common_words and score intent based on the list.
    # return common_words, intent_score
    return common_words
```

## utilities for intersection & spellchecking

```
def intersection(a,b):
    """
    a and b are lists
    function returns a list that is the intersection of the two
    """
    return list(set(a)&set(b))



def spellcheck_subject_matter_specific(rawinput,subject_matter_vector,threshold=0.01,capitalize=True,debug=False):
    """
    rawinput: all the text that you want to check for spelling
    subject_matter_vector: only the words that are worth spellchecking for (since the function can be sort of sensitive it might correct words that you don't want to correct)
    threshold: the spell check confidence needed to update the word to the correct spelling
    capitalize: boolean determining if you want the return string to be capitalized.
    """

    new_input = copy.copy(rawinput)

    for w in TextBlob(rawinput).words:
        spellchecked_vec = w.spellcheck()
        if debug:
            print "Word: %s" %w
            print "Spellchecked Guesses & Confidences: %s" %spellchecked_vec
            print "Only spellchecked confidences greater than {} and in this list {} will be included".format(threshold,subject_matter_vector)

        corrected_words = [z[0].upper() for z in spellchecked_vec if z[1] > threshold] 
        important_words = intersection(corrected_words,subject_matter_vector)
        for new_word in important_words:

            new_input = new_input + ' ' + new_word


    inputBlob = TextBlob(new_input)
    processed_input = inputBlob.words
    if capitalize:
        processed_input = [word.upper() for word in processed_input]

    return processed_input
```

## Usage Example

```
discord_str = "Hi, i want to talk about codee and pYtHon"

words2detect = ["python","code"]

score_intent(rawstring=discord_str,keywords=words2detect,threshold=0.01,debug=True)
```

## output

> ```
> intent score: 2
> words of interest found in text: ['PYTHON', 'CODE']
> ```

Comment: Holy cow what a thorough answer.

Comment: Something tells me OP might find it a bit overwhelming though haha.